# Matching a fixed list and a variable length list and return binary mask based on a fixed list

Tags: python

Given a fixed list

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

and a variable length list `y1`, `y2`, `y3` which have possible values drawn from `x` , for example

```
y1 = ["a", "b", "b"]
y2 = ["c", "e"]
y3 = ["a", "b", "d", "e", "e", "a", "b"]
```

Is there an effective and scalable way to get the output `out1`, `out2`, `out3` for `y1`, `y2`, `y3` respectively as follows.  My data has many many `y` and I'm trying to minimize looping.

```
out1 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]    because a and b existed in x
out2 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]    because c and e existed in x
out3 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]    because a, b, d, e existed in x
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do set conversions, so the contains-checks will be `O(1)`. Other than that you will need  iterations of some sort

```
s1, s2, s3 = map(set, (y1, y2, y3))

out1 = [int(e in s1) for e in x]
out2 = [int(e in s2) for e in x]
out3 = [int(e in s3) for e in x]
```

You could go for the more functional:

```
out1 = [*map(int, map(s1.__contains__, x))]
```

Or, omitting the `int`-cast (as bools are integers already in Python)

```
out1 = [*map(s1.__contains__, x)]
```

Comment: convert `list` to `set` already takes `O(n)`, right? so i think `O(1)` makes no sense here.

Comment: I only claim that the contains-check (`e in s1`) is `O(1)`, nothing more nothing less. Where do I state anything beyond that?

Comment: i was just wondering the whole function is O(1) at first glance. anyway, your syntax is amazing!

Comment: @LeiYang The claim was that the individual membership tests are O(1) when using a set, rather than O(n) when using a list.  That check is made O(n) times for each x, y pair, so the time for a given x, y pair is O(n), rather than O(n**2) if list membership had been used.  This is very basic to Python (and data structures in general), and is the main reason why sets (and dicts) exist in Python.

Comment: @TomKarzes partly agree. but if 'This is very basic to Python', why mention it at all in answer?

Comment: @LeiYang Because many of the people here are unfamiliar with the basics of Python in particular, and data structures in general.  That's why 2 of the 3 originally posted answers used list membership rather than set membership.  Many of the people here are largely self-taught (or are students), and don't have degrees in computer science.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, all the elements in `yn` are guaranteed to be in `x`, so your binary masks tell you what elements of `x` are NOT in `yn`.

If you're not set to use binary masks, a possible solution using sets is as follows

```
>>> a = set((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
>>> b = set((6,7))
>>> a - b
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9])
>>>
```

---

Tank you @TomKarzes for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266851/matching-a-fixed-list-and-a-variable-length-list-and-return-binary-mask-based-on/68267313#comment120654006_68267313).

Comment: but this is not expected result, am i mistaking?

Comment: @TomKarzes I know, this is not what the OP asked for, but possibly it's what they really need.  As I stated initially (_"If you're not set to use binary masks"_), each binary mask tells what elements of `x` are not in `y`, and depending on the (unspecified)  task that must be performed, the set `x-(x&y)` COULD be equivalent to the binary mask and COULD (benchmark anyone?) be way faster.

Comment: @LeiYang Please understand that I'm well aware my result is not what the OP asked for. I tried to address this in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266851/matching-a-fixed-list-and-a-variable-length-list-and-return-binary-mask-based-on/68267313#comment120653821_68267313).

Comment: @TomKarzes Ooops,  should had known better, but I was coming from `x&y` to find what elements of `y` are in `x`, and only later I realized that the OP wanted the elements of `x` that are not in `y` …